# Modeling the maximum number of moves in Tower of Hanoi problem

Tags: algorithms, recursion

What would be the recursive algorithm for solving the Tower of Hanoi problem (with n disks and 3 pegs) in maximal number of moves (i.e. going through all possible disks/pegs combinations).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

In the initial position there are three towers, that I will call A,B,C, and assume the problem we want to solve recursively is:

> **Problem:** Move all disks located in tower $X$ to tower $Y$ (for $X,Y\in \{A,B,C\}$ and $X\neq Y$).

The recursive solution is as follows:

- For $n=1$ disks: move the disk from $X$ to $Y$.
- For $n=k+1$ disks:

  1. Use the solution for $k$ disks to move the first $k$ disks from tower $X$ to the tower $Z$, namely the only tower in the set $\{A,B,C\}\setminus \{X,Y\}$.
  2. Move the $(k+1)$-th disk to tower $Y$.
  3. Use the solution for $k$ disks to move the first $k$ disks from tower $Z$ to tower $Y$.

With this, the number of moves is recursively defined as:

$$\begin{cases}M_1=1\\ M_{k+1}=2M_k+1\end{cases}$$ which have the following general formula:

$$M_n=1+2+\ldots+2^{n-1}=2^n-1$$

Comment: Err, $M_n = 2^n - 1$.

Comment: @BrianO You are right!... it is impossible for an even number to be equal to an odd number

Comment: there is only one sequence of moves / algorithm for solving the Hanoi towers problem (the one you described), all the others just insert un-necessary sequences of moves that cancel themselves ?

Comment: Yes. To prove you can have in mind that in order to move one disk you first have to remove all disks of smaller size over it.

Comment: I mean this is the answer to his question

Comment: @Wore The proposed solution solves the problem in minimal number of moves if im correct. What I need is the solution for maximal number of moves. The number of moves for maximal move solution will always be (3^^n -1) but what I'm looking for is pattern that could be used as an algorithm. For example for minimal number of moves you always move (n-1) disks on a spare peg and then move the biggest disk to the "end" peg and then move those n-1 disks to the end peg.

Comment: @Domba I do not understand what you mean with maximal number of moves. In principle, you can just the same disk over and over again between different towers and will give you solutions with arbitrarily large number of moves. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wore I solved my problem in the meantime. Hmm, I hadn't expressed myself good enough since noone here understood the issue. This picture might bring the problem closer to you ( https://www.google.hr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0gZD1kabNAhXMWxoKHVJ0AJgQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ATower_of_Hanoi_3-disk_graph_-_longest_path.svg&psig=AFQjCNHIyopERY41ONZ5OCHRxzUGmsC3sg&ust=1465946365894171 ) The path in this picture is the solution to my problem when there are 3 disks and I was looking for a general solution for n disks.

Comment: What I forgot to mention was that every specific situation (represented by a node on the picture I linked in my comment before) mustn't occur more than once. With that condition, there is only one longest path from the state where all disks are on one peg to the state where all disks are on some other peg. In the end, I solved the problem by recognizing a pattern in the disk movement, not by recursion.